# Change existing svn repository file for new ones

Tags: wordpress, git, svn

I got a wordpress plugin in the wp.org svn repository located in c:\plugin . Now I started the plugin from scratch on a new folder in my drive c:\plugins\plugin and now I want to know how to replace the existing svn with the new files so I can tag the new version.

I use git on the new location.

On the old location I have the working svn c:\plugin\tags c:\plugin\trunk , etc

I don't want to mess with svn and end submitting an incomplete plugin or broken plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: don't do it that way, ever again. Why have version control at all, if you don't use it? Get a working copy, and work from there.

To get your current code into the repository, simply check out a working copy, and copy your existing work into it. Then `svn add` any new files, `svn rm` any files that need deleting, and `svn commit` the bunch.

Comment: I did this way because the plugin was completely different from original. not even one file was the same. Should I svn rm * in old location, then checkout on new and svn add ?

Comment: You could but then there is a revision with no content. Probably better to svn rm everything, copy in the new, and svn add in one commit. Is there really nothing the same or similar to use svn mv for?